# Which marker did user click on (ArcGIs JS API)?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a simple map with a set of 10 markers on it. When they are clicked an infoWindow appears however I would like to instead display the data in the infoWindow in a table.

How do I find out which marker was clicked?

This is the code I'm using to determine which marker was clicked:

```
          // Find the identity of the marker that was clicked
          featureLayer.clearSelection();
          var selectQuery = new esri.tasks.Query();
          var tol = map.extent.getWidth()/map.width * 10;
          var x = evt.mapPoint.x;
          var y = evt.mapPoint.y;
          var queryExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(x-tol,y-tol,x+tol,y+tol,evt.mapPoint.spatialReference);
          selectQuery.geometry = queryExtent;
          var t = featureLayer.selectFeatures(selectQuery,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
          console.log(t.results[0][0][0].attributes);
```

This partially works, however when the map zooms out this code will sometimes the wrong marker information. I'm thinking that I can change the queryExtent variable to account for the zoom level of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce it but there is an easier way to get clicked feature from FeatureLayer.

This is sample code:

```
dojo.connect(featureLayer, "onClick", function (evt) {
    var graphicAttributes = evt.graphic.attributes;
    //do anything ...
});
```